# Subgit migration stuck and stops at commits with large files

Tags: git, subgit

I am doing a migration from subversion to git using subgit. Subversion has a revision where large number of files (aprox 3GB) were committed accidentally. I am using "excludePath" parameter to avoid those large useless files. When I run subgit , it stuck at this mentioned revision and finally process stop after around 2 hours not completing the migration. 
On subgit log I could see some files were retrieved on that revision and after that line there is nothing in the log. What might be the problem I am facing?

**Please Note** : I only changed the excludePath parameter and svn-url in subgit/config, others were kept default. and I am running this on linux

Comment: At this moment 'excludePath' influences only on the fact whether to include or not files into Git commit but the SVN server sends the content of the files anyway. Maybe in the future this behaviour could be optimized to tell SVN not to send excluded paths, but at the moment of writing this comment it's not. So you could just wait until the operation completion.